# sudo apt-get install -f aborts when i key in "Y" or "yes"

Tags: apt, package-management

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cabextract fonts-wine libjemalloc1 libllvm6.0:i386 libllvm7 libllvm7:i386
  libmspack0 libwine libwine:i386 libwine-development libwine-development:i386
  wine32:i386 wine32-development:i386 wine64 wine64-development
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aptitude:i386 aptitude-common libapt-pkg5.0:i386
  libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386 libboost-iostreams1.65.1:i386
  libboost-system1.65.1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libcwidget3v5:i386
  libncursesw5:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libxapian30:i386 libzstd1:i386
Suggested packages:
  aptitude-doc-en:i386 | aptitude-doc:i386 apt-xapian-index:i386 debtags:i386
  tasksel:i386 libcwidget-dev:i386 xapian-tools:i386
Recommended packages:
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 apt:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils code packages-microsoft-prod
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-notifier
  update-notifier-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude-common libapt-pkg5.0:i386 libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386
  libboost-iostreams1.65.1:i386 libboost-system1.65.1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libcwidget3v5:i386 libncursesw5:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libxapian30:i386
  libzstd1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aptitude:i386
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt
1 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 12 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,892 kB of archives.
After this operation, 227 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?] y
Abort.
```

Comment: Well, `y` is not *the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'*. What issue are you trying to solve, exactly? `apt` is clearly trying to stop you from doing something potentially damaging.

Comment: What is your main CPU architecture? Please add output of `arch` and `uname -m` to the question.

Comment: `apt-mark showmanual | grep apt` please too.

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to install `aptitude` package manager, which was replaced by `apt-get` in 2011. Is there any specific reason you are doing this?

Comment: @AngelAraya could you please give any proof-link for your wrong sentence "... `aptitude` package manager, which was replaced by `apt-get` in 2011." . For example https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_basic_package_management_operations and https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html do not state this. So you spread misinformation. It is more-powerful advanced tool and not the replacement.

Comment: @N0rbert I never debated which one is more powerful or advanced. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/592336/comments/19. Perhaps replaced was the not the right wording, but it was removed from the default ISO due to space constraints at the time.

Answer (score 1):

As @steeldriver comments, `y` is not the phrase `Yes, do as I say!`

It seems that the action you are trying to make could potentially damage your system by removing important packages. In the `apt` output you can read:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apt-transport-https apt-utils code packages-microsoft-prod
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk update-manager update-notifier
  update-notifier-common
```

`apt` is making sure you want remove `apt`. If this is what you want to do and *know* how to fix it in case it is not, then you can continue.